# MySQL Optimizing OR IN SELECT

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm having a hard time optimizing a query like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions AS t
  INNER JOIN users AS u
    ON u = t.user_id
WHERE (
  u.id = 123
  OR u.id IN (
    SELECT user_id FROM users_parents AS up
    WHERE up.parent_id = 123
  )
)
```

I've boiled it down to the essential and changed the field names for simpleness as the fields aren't in English so if there is any syntax mistakes it will be most likely because of that.

The query needs to return all the transactions from a certain (parent) user, or any user that is associated with the parent user

However, because of the usage of an IN SELECT the performance is terrible, its taking me over 6 seconds to run this query on a small portion of the database, the whole query database takes over 600s!

I've read that I should use JOINs but all my tries are giving me different end results on the query, I think I'm stuck doing something wrong syntax wise and I can't find my own logical / syntax flaws as I've been spending too many hours looking at it and doing / redoing the same code over and over.

The database structure is rather simple,

```
= transactions 
id|user_id|....
= users
id|....
= users_parents
id|parent_id|user_id
```

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure how it runs without error, but should the join condition not be `ON u.id = t.user_id` instead of `ON u = t.user_id`?

Comment: @DarshanMehta - Absolutely, I must have overwritten it while rewriting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT transactions.*, users.*
FROM transactions AS t
JOIN users AS u ON u.id = t.user_id
LEFT JOIN users_parents up on up.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = 123 or up.parent_id = 123
```

ps. I suppose user to parent is n to 1.(1 user only have 1 parent, different user can have same parent).

Comment: @Zjahn glad to help